# Laravel bad wordfilter as an helper

Tags: php, laravel, filter

I'm trying to make my own bad word filter, and it works great, exept when I have multiple words in a sentence. So now What it does is, it takes the values out of the database and then loops trugh it and must replace the ad words.

Let me say I have (in dutch) this sentence: `Deze kanker zooi moet eens stoppen! Het is godverdomme altijd het zelfde zooitje.`. These are the words that must been replaced in the database:

`kanker` and `godverdomme`.

So I have in my database:

[image: values]

Thats all good, exept when the 2 ords must been replaced, then it doesn't want to replace...

My helper function:

```
public static function Filter($value)
    {
        $badwords = DB::table('badwords')->get();

        foreach ($badwords as $badword)
        {
            $replaced = str_ireplace($badword->bad_word, $badword->replacement, $value);
        }

    return $replaced;
    }
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Kindest regards,

Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each iteration in your foreach loop, you set the value of `$replaced` to whatever `str_ireplace` returns.
At the end of the function you will return a value where *only* the last bad word should have been replaced.

`str_ireplace` takes either a single string value or an array of string values to replace as first and second parameter which means that you instead could create two arrays, which you fill in the`foreach` loop and then run the `str_ireplace` after the loop, something like:

```
$words = []; 
$replace = [];
foreach ($badwords as $badword) {
    array_push($words, $badword->bad_word);
    array_push($replace, $badword->replacement);
}
return str_ireplace($words, $replace, $value);
```

Comment: So acutually when I create an array object of the two variables, it shoult work.